# To search attribute name(column name) of core data if the values in that attribute is given in iOS(objective c)

Tags: core-data, attributes

I want to search attribute name(column name) of core data if the values in that attribute is given in iOS(objective c). I want to get values from column from core data if one value of column is selected beacuse I am displaying a row from core data and if any one value from that row is selected the whole column value should retreive. Pls help me with this.

Comment: updating the post with code will help others help you better

Comment: You search using `NSPredicate`. If you need more detail, please improve your question, because right now it's difficult to tell what help you might need.

Answer (score 0):

I understood and solved the problem. Actually after clicking on any row cell I want to display column of that row. from core data so I was not understanding how to call that column without attribute name. Since what I was having was value of that column. So what I did is made a multidimensional array in which I added that row value with the column name. below is the code.
 [popupTimingArray insertObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:puneTrainkeyName[i],timeArray[i],nil]; 
and then i used predicate
NSArray *filtered = [popupTimingArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",keyname]];
 To get the related attribute name with that selected row value.
But still I want to know cant we fetch column(attribute name from core data)
And I also want to know that In my project there is many information is to be saved in project itself. So which is the best Core data or sqlite.
Thanks